# SageMaker exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create a model on AWS Sagemaker by triggering it from Java.

The steps I am following are the following,

- Upload the csv of the training data with the target field as the first one - WORKED
- Create a Training Job using SageMaker by using createTrainingJob API from the AWS SDK - Issue here

I am getting the following exception while I try to create the image

`Cannot find the requested image: 777445444252.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sagemakerimage with tag: latest and digest: null. Please check if your ECR image exists and role arn:aws:iam::777445444252:role/sagemaker has proper pull permissions for SageMaker: ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability, ecr:BatchGetImage, ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer`

I have created role `sagemaker` with permissions as,
[image]
so that it can access all repositories in ECR with full permissions.

I have also made sure I have the repository `sagemakerimage` created in ECR
But I still get this error. I am not sure what is wrong in what I am trying to do.

Also, I thought the image was supposed to be created?

Comment: I am not an expert, so just guessing.. is there any possibility that the image has not been tagged with "latest" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow along with the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javav2-sagemaker-src-main-java-com-example-sage-CreateTrainingJob.java.html) to create a training job using Java API and make sure the region in which the ECR image is same as your reference and is tagged appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the docker image is pulled not by your role but by the sagemaker role (look for something like `Sagemaker_role` in IAM.) This role transfer is done because Sagemaker requires iam:PassRole which changes the role of the job from the caller (you) to the sagemaker role `Sagemaker_role`. It seems that `Sagemaker_role` doesn't have permissions to pull an image from ECR. The role being used is based on the role you pass to [EstimatorBase](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase) (python api but roughly similar.)